# Rails custom validation checking for duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

A table has following fields: badge_id, output_id, timely, removed, updated_at. For each badge_id, there can't have two valid records with the same output_id. But it doesn't mean that (badge_id, output_id) is a unique combination. Removed column indicates the current row has been removed or not. Basically delete or update operation triggers inserting a new row in the table with the latest change. So for example, we have a record like this:

```
badge_id| output_id| removed| timely | updated_at
1       | 1        | N      | Y      | 2013-11-26
```

To remove that record, we actually insert another row and now it reads like

```
badge_id| output_id| removed| timely | updated_at
1       | 1        | N      | Y      | 2013-11-26
1       | 1        | Y      | Y      | 2013-11-27
```

Because the latest record of (badge_id: 1, output_id: 1) has removed column set, it means that combination has been deleted. But I can't have two rows of same (badge_id: 1, output_id: 1), both have removed as "N" like:

```
badge_id| output_id| removed| timely | updated_at
1       | 1        | N      | N      | 2013-11-26
1       | 1        | N      | Y      | 2013-11-27
```

So every time to add a new output_id for a certain badge_id, I have to check for duplication. But usual validates uniqueness of (badge_id, output_id) from ActiveModel doesn't work here. How do I write a clean custom validation for this? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I think I might have missed some key points. A record can be added and then deleted and then added repeatedly. So a combination of (badge_id, output_id, removed) isn't unique either. When add a new record, we need to check for (badge_id, output_id), whether **latest** record has removed set as 'Y' or not.

So for possible answer like

```
validate_uniqueness_of :badge_id, scope: [:output_id], 
conditions: -> { where(removed: "N") }
```

At the condition where clause, it should have order by updated_at desc and the first one has removed: 'N'. How do I fit that kind of condition into this one line code? Or there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
validates :unique_badge_and_output_ids
```

Then `unique_badge_and_output_ids` could be:

```
def unique_badge_and_output_ids
  unless Object.find_by_badge_id_and_output_id_and_removed(self.badge_id, self.output_id, self.removed).blank?
    self.errors.add "record already exists" # obviously a better error here would be ideal
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an SQL condition on validates_uniqueness_of:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of

> It is also possible to limit the uniqueness constraint to a set of
>   records matching certain conditions. In this example archived articles
>   are not being taken into consideration when validating uniqueness of
>   the title attribute:
>
> ```
> class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
>   validates_uniqueness_of :title, conditions: -> { where.not(status: 'archived') } 
> end
> ```

So in your example:

```
class YourModel < AR::Base
  validate_uniqueness_of :badge_id, scope: [:output_id], 
    conditions: -> { where(removed: "N") }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand your use case properly.

Try validating the uniqueness of the `removed` and scoping it to both the `badge_id` and `output_id` columns but only when the removed field is N:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :removed, 
    scope: [:badge_id, :output_id], 
    conditions: -> { where.not(removed: 'Y') }
end
```

There's a chance it might just work.